# Ansible temporary script not found

Tags: ansible

I've checked other answers and the problem I'm encountering isn't fixed by changing the remote (or local) temporary directory.

One of my hosts (not all of them) is failing with the message:

```
fatal: [wazuh_elastic_server]: FAILED! => {"ansible_job_id": "872609276122.14706", "changed": false, "cmd": "/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567526428.5-44355784464580/AnsiballZ_apt.py", "finished": 1, "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567526428.5-44355784464580/AnsiballZ_apt.py': '/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1567526428.5-44355784464580/AnsiballZ_apt.py'", "outdata": "", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": []}
```

The task is:

```
- name: Linux | Install wazuh-agent
  package: name=wazuh-agent state=present
  async: 90
  poll: 15
  tags:
    - init
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Check to see if that directory exists.

Comment: It doesn't exist, there are multiple other directories in the ansible tmp directory (other commands are working)